# How compressed is Chat GPT data?

Tags: chatgpt, memory

I originally thought the Chat GPT was a neural network model in which the input data was highly compressed such that the input data could not be got out again.

But then I asked Chat GPT "**Write the whole text of Alice and Wonderland**".

And it was able to write the text word for word. 100% correctly. (For as long as I cared to read it for).

Therefor it seems like any paragraph of text it has read in its dataset more than once it seems to have stored it verbatim. (Perhaps like a human actor who can memorise a script).

If Chat GPT has enough weights in its neural network it could theoretically store every item of input text it has fed to it.

I wonder does the attention model have the happy accident that it is able to remember whole books of text?

I wonder how much of the input text could it remember verbatim. Or perhaps it will only remember famous works like Alice in Wonderland because they would be repeated many times in the input data.

Comment: This is unfortunately impossible to answer until OpenAI releases a scientific paper describing how ChatGPT works. Currently there is no details available.